# Excel: Using MATCH as row argument of OFFSET

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Cell F10 is a choice-box: 'Best', 'Base', 'Worst' case. I'm trying to change Revenue growth (F11) based on that selection.

How do I use match as the row argument of the OFFSET function in cell F11 to change revenue growth based on the scenario selected in cell F10? I'm using cell D5 a starting/reference point in my formula.

My incorrect attempted solution: **OFFSET(D5, MATCH($F$10, $C$14:$C$16,0),0)**

[image]

Comment: Your formula seems to work just fine - If you have values in `D6-D8`, they should appear in the cell where you place this formula... What are you experiencing???

Comment: I'm experiencing suspiciously large values for revenue growth (cell F11). Somewhere near %10000!

Comment: ... Without seeing the values you have in your sheet, it's impossible for me to know if that makes sense or not - I can tell you, though, that the formula you're using will work.... Are you sure you're not just formatting things as percentage and therefore the numbers look bigger or something else like that???

Comment: Oh, sorry, if you supplied a picture, my ISP blocks them... I only saw your typed in text... Good luck!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you need the result to be 24%, 20% or 16%? If so then you have the wrong start point for OFFSET, try

`=OFFSET(F13,MATCH($F$10,$C$14:$C$16,0),0)`

although VLOOKUP might be better, i.e.

`=VLOOKUP(F10,$C$14:F$16,4,0)`

For your example with "base case" in F10 either formula should return 20%. Is that right? Do you also want to multiply that by something? Perhaps indicate the value you expect to see in F11 given the sample values in your example.